# Is there any way to switch on or off debug lines in the entire Python project?

Tags: python, logging

I'm working on a project with more than 35 individual python modules, divided into three packages, and many are interconnected. Previously, I was using prints for printing some info while debugging and removed those lines from the final code.

I'm looking for a solution to turn those lines on or off with just one top-level switch. Which is the most efficient way to do that? Our program does some of the very demanding operations. The best solution should completely avoid parsing debug lines instead of suppressing their outputs; I believe that can save some resources and improve speed.

Comment: Read the [logging how-to](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html)!

Comment: Hey, thanks. I was through it once. The one thing I don't find in it is to stop logging when not needed. My debugging outputs generally have lots of complex execution to understand what went wrong and sometimes exporting files that can take time. I want to avoid all these when I'm not debugging, but actually running the program.  Debugging here does not specifically mean I run the program in debug mode. I sometimes run it like normal but add print/export lines to just know some parameters at a certain location in program.

Comment: instead on turn on/of print, you can use python's logging module, and can set/change the log level ( debug, info...) just by changing the configuration.

Comment: To stop the logging, define all your log as debug. log.debug('some logs...'), and after testing, set the log level to 'INFO', so none of the debug logs are generated

Comment: This sounds like you are over-logging. Please give and example of a complex debug logging!

Comment: Hi @KlausD. I'm not using logging yet, but do manual debugging. My need is to turn those complex debug lines on or off when I need instead of manually commenting out or removing those lines from the final code.
Also, the program takes files and modifies them; modification is done at several levels depending on the file itself. When the output is not what I expected, I need to export just a portion or the complete file from a specific point in the program.  Doing it manually takes a lot of time, I can use this on-off mechanism I guess. 

Thanks

Comment: Obviously you need **logging**. You can use the native `logging` library, or, you could use something like **`loguru`**: https://github.com/Delgan/loguru.

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what Python [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html) is built for. Besides allowing you to set logging level in centralised way, it includes an optimisation that avoids evaluation of arguments passed to logging calls whose level is lower that current one.

In this example the logging level of the application (there can be more modules, own or 3rd party that have their loggers) is controlled from one place, [`basicConfig`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) call. Also note that when `level=logging.INFO` expensive `repr` of `AggregateRoot` is not calculated.

```
import logging
import time

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class AggregateRoot:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def work(self, n):
        time.sleep(1 / n)

    def __repr__(self):        
        time.sleep(1)  # say, it takes a few ORM calls to build the repr
        return f'AggregateRoot({self.kwargs})'

def main():
    obj = AggregateRoot(foo='bar')
    n = 42
    logger.debug('Calling work of %s with n=%d', obj, n)
    try:
        obj.work(n)
    except ValueError:
        logger.exception('Work failed for n=%d', n)
    else:
        logger.info('Work succeeded')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(
        level=logging.DEBUG,
        #level=logging.INFO,
        format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)08s %(name)s %(message)s',
    )
    main()
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I believe, it answers my question.